# How to aggregate in Sql

Tags: sql

I would like to aggregate the below ID's and extract datetime into a month column.

My sql query seems to not aggregate when I bring in the date because the date field has date time.

This is dummy data.

```
Select Id,Area_Name,first_name,surname,Action_start_time,Month(Action_Start_time) [Month], count(id) Volume
From [Car dealership].[dbo].[Car Calls]
Group by Area_Name,first_name,surname,Id,Action_start_time;
```

[image]

This is what I get. Even when I remove the Action Start time. I still dont get the aggregation to work.

Comment: do you want to do it by just the date ignoring the time?

Comment: I want to do it by month. I would like to aggregate all Id's by month

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you just remove the Action_start_time from the select?

Use the Month(Action_start_time) function inside the group by clause.

```
Select Id,Area_Name,first_name,surname,Month(Action_Start_time) [Month], count(id) Volume From [Car dealership].[dbo].[Car Calls]
Group by Area_Name,first_name,surname,Id,Month(Action_start_time);
```